# How to define a page in terms of a block?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, block

I learnt that when we manage a data structure such as a tree or other graph its nodes are stored in the computer in something called a block and nodes of the graph can make up the block and it is the block that is transferred between secondary and primary memory when a data structure gets moved between primary and secondary memory. So I think it's pretty clear what a block is, it can consist of different sizes depending on architecture but is often 4K. Now I want to know how a block relates to memory *pages*. Do pages consist of blocks or what is the relation of blocks to pages? Can we define what a page is in memory in terms of a block?

Comment: As memory management is system specific I think you would need to at the very least restrict the question to a specific operating system. Speculatively here's a link to a wiki that describes memory management on Linux, http://linux-mm.org/

Comment: You typically try to define a block so it's either the same size as a memory page, or at least evenly divisible so an integral number of blocks will fit in a page.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the link. I'm interested in both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically try to define a block so it's either the same size as a memory page, or its size is evenly divisible by the size of a memory page, so an integral number of blocks will fit in a page.

As you mentioned, 4K tends to work well -- typical memory page sizes are 4K and 8K. Most also support at least one larger page size (e.g., 1 megabyte) but you can typically more or less ignore them; they're used primarily for mapping single, large chunks of contiguous memory (e.g., the part of graphics memory that's directly visible to the CPU).